# terminated with SIGABRT

Tags: git, tslint, husky, git-husky

I am using [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) for linting files before commit files.

But today suddenly getting some weird issue like below

```
╰─ node_modules/husky/run.js pre-commit husky > pre-commit (node v10.15.0)   ↓ Stashing changes... [skipped]
    → No partially staged files found...   ❯ Running tasks...
    ❯ Running tasks for {src}/**/*.{js,ts}
      ✖ tslint -c tslint.json
        git add



⚠ tslint -c tslint.json was terminated with SIGABRT
 husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass).
```

I have tried google and many StackOverflow link but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. An abort signal can come from various points, but the most common case is a self-check. The `tslint ... was terminated with SIGABRT` therefore indicates that `tslint` failed some internal self-check and stopped (presumably to avoid damaging things). You'll want to look into what tslint was doing.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using the `-- no-verify` flag at the end of the commit command and since my project had checks running on GitHub for `lint` so if those failed then the issue lies in the code and if not then it must be an issue with the text editor.